# Static content in url routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

i am having two routes

```
   context.MapRoute("",
                "Route1/{controller}/{programid}/{action}"
            );

   context.MapRoute("",
                "Route2/{controller}/{programid}/{action}"
            );
```

Url.Action("action2", "controller2", new{programid = 123});

Resultant URL : Route1/controller2/123/action2

Is it possible to get the url below:

Expected URL : Route2/controller2/123/action2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your route as

```
context.MapRoute("Route1", 
            "Route1/{controller}/{programid}/{action}"
        );

context.MapRoute("Route2",
            "Route2/{controller}/{programid}/{action}"
        );
```

Then use [Url.RouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) like

```
Url.RouteUrl("Route1", YourRouteProperties }
```

or

```
Url.RouteUrl("Route1", new { controller = "YourController", action = "YourAction", 
 programid= "YourProgramId"}}
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there any option with Url.Action method, bcas i need to mention action, controller in the method itself.

Comment: @sathishkumar, You can sure pass controller, action

Comment: Thanks machi(friend), But it is not possible with the URL.Action() method right?